# Have more than 18 Start Menu Items with Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

Is there a way to enlarge the Windows 11 start menu that it does show more than 18 favoured start menu items ?

Answer (score 19):

Windows 11 contains a dramatically simplified Start menu and taskbar,
both of which lack many of the power-user options of Windows 10.
You can't resize the Start menu or the taskbar
and you can't position the taskbar on different sides of the screen.

Users have been crying foul, so it's possible that Microsoft will
in the future return these features.
Until it does, you could use some third-party alternatives to Microsoft's
Start menu.

Here are some of them:

- [Open-Shell-Menu](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/) (free).
  Emulates the Windows 7 menu.
- [StartAllBack](https://www.startallback.com/) (free).
  Emulates Windows 7 and 10.
- [Stardock Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/)
  (€6.99 with trial).
  The most complete : Emulates Windows 7, 10 and 11.

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I wanted to see more than 18 items at once.

Comment: These alternatives allow the resizing of their Start menu, so you'll be able to extend it to the limits of your screen.

Comment: Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: @BonitaMontero If MS can not do that, it is the fault of the MS. Imho the answer describes the shortest path to have a 18+ start menu, and while I agree your unsatisfiedness, I think the MS is to blame and not harrymc.

Comment: @BonitaMontero (Btw, I always avoid any MS OS upgrade until I can, exactly on this reason - experience is that I can always count with many similar pity, unexplainable feature removal)

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a way to enlarge the Windows 11 start menu that it does show
> more than 18 favoured start menu items ?

The Windows 11 Start menu can hold more than 18 items, but the size of the menu is fixed and cannot be changed.

Also the things that you value most can be moved to the top - you are not bound by what Microsoft deems to be favorite.

You can add and drag items to the Start Menu and then sort them as you wish.

Also notice the buttons at the side of the Start Menu. This allows "pages" in the Start Menu and allows you to scroll through the entire list.

To put it another way, put your 18 most used items to the top of the menu and you do not have to scroll very much at all.

The main Start menu size in Windows 11, however,  cannot be natively changed with Windows 11 settings.

I can readily use the dots on the side of the menu to get between pages very quickly. I also use my desktop for highly used apps (Office, Email, Adobe, and like) which can reduce dependence on the Start Menu, which can then be used for lesser used apps. It depends on individual needs.

I am not hampered by the Windows 11 Start Menu in any way. I just adapted to it.

[image: Windows 11 Start Menu]

Comment: "It is really quite flexible." <-- I disagree with this. You've shown multiple ways on how incredibly restrictive the Start Menu is, and then you say it is flexible. Are you sure you meant "flexible"?

Comment: I can easily manage the Start Menu and 3 dozen or more start menu items. I am not hampered in any way. that is what I mean by flexible. I put most needed icons on my desktop (I always did this) and that helps with the start menu as well.

Comment: I think it is better that you clarify that in your answer, as the current wording makes it seem that you think it is flexible when it is objectively inflexible, specially when comparing to Windows 10 - a currently supported version of the Windows Operating System "family". Clarifying what you meant by "flexible" would only add value to your answer.

Comment: Reasonable point and I re-wrote that section to indicate how I use it and the Desktop and that I am not hampered.

Comment: And I've upvoted your answer. Thank you for taking criticism so well. It's really rare now-a-days. However, it is interesting how you use the desktop for programs you use more commonly, instead of the start menu, as I rely heavily on the start menu to open all my most common programs. I have the right-side populated with tiles, specifically placed so I can remember where the icon is and just open what I want, very quickly.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I find it interesting too, as I no longer use desktop icons anymore. Simply press Windows key then start typing the name, or click on the top 6-10 icons I've pinned there.

Comment: I find it incredibly dismaying that people **still** think the desktop is a place to put icons.  It's a horrible paradigm.  You can't display in any ordered way, or in "Details/LIst" format, some icons are system-based and some are user-based, etc.   Just Don't Do It

Comment: That is not correct. You can display Desktop Icons in any order you wish - system or otherwise. You can display Windows 11 Start Menu items in any order you want - System or otherwise. Then depending on personal preference, users may have major apps on the desktop.  That has worked flawlessly for me since Windows 95.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: `Settings > Personalization > Start > Layout > [x] More Pins`

[image]